# Handling uploaded resources for local development

Tags: files

With our Drupal site we develop locally, commit to svn and deploy to the live site. Some content gets uploaded on the live site (some images, videos etc). I am trying to sort out the best way to handle those uploaded resources.

Currently, we do daily database dumps, and use those for local development, but if someone has edited a page and added an image, it will 404 on the local since the image doesn't exist.

I rsync content down, but not all the team has ssh access (security). Should I tar up the uploaded assets at the same time as the database dumps? Or, is there a better way to handle this?

Basically; Whats the best way of getting uploaded content, for local development?

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/stage_file_proxy

Answer (score 0):

Yes your database and files need to be kept in sync to avoid 404s as you describe. 
With our setup all developers have access to a backed up copy of the database and files. The backups of both database and files are synchronised so together they're essentially a snapshot of the production site. I personally use a collection of Drush commands wrapped up in a shell script in order to restore this snapshot to my local machine.